# chrome extension run script after ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am new to Javascript, and I am creating a chrome extension where I am trying to inject some HTMLs into the existing public website,

My current code is something like this,

```
if (document.readyState ==='complete'){
  inject_html();
}
```

However, on the current website, when a button is pressed, ajax is processed and new HTML DOM is loaded for the same url, so the script doesn't run.

Is there a way to listen to whenever ajax is finished processing? What is the best way in this case, can an expert help me?

Comment: Try using .done()

http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

Comment: It depends on the site. Sometimes it's better to listen to `"message"` on `window`, or custom events, or a mutation observer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Extension : content script on facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672230/chrome-extension-content-script-on-facebook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather hacky, but you can override any property (and thus interpose any method call) of the `XMLHttpRequest` prototype, as well as the function/constructor itself.
The most convenient thing to do in your case is probably to hook the `XMLHttpRequest` function itself, and simply add an event listener there:

```
var originalXHR = XMLHttpRequest;
XMLHttpRequest = function()
{
    var ret = new originalXHR();
    ret.addEventListener('load', function()
    {
        console.log('Ajax request finished!');
    });
    return ret;
};
```

The control flow here goes like this:

- Call original function
- Modify return value
- Return modified value

This takes advantage of the fact that if in JavaScript a constructor returns a value, that value replaces the object created with `new`.

In action:

```js
// Interface code
var field = document.querySelector('input');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function()
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // crossorigin.me because we need a CORS proxy for most external URLs
    xhr.open("GET", 'https://crossorigin.me/' + field.value);
    xhr.send(null);
});

// Hooking code
var originalXHR = XMLHttpRequest;
XMLHttpRequest = function()
{
    var ret = new originalXHR();
    ret.addEventListener('load', function(ev)
    {
        // var xhr = ev.target;
        console.log('Ajax request finished!');
    });
    return ret;
};
```

```html
<!-- Demo page: -->
URL: <input type="text" value="https://google.com"><br>
<button>Load via XHR</button>
```

Note that this only gives you a method to detect *when* an XHR has finished loading, and not control over its return value. From within the function that does `console.log`, you do however have access to the XHR itself, via `ev.target`.

You could also create hooking points to modify the loaded content before it reaches the code on the page, but that would require a couple more hooks, because listeners can be added in more than one way (`.onload`, `.onreadystatechange`, `.addEventListener`, etc), but it would be doable if necessary.