# Content script doesn't get injected on every page load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a basic content script in my `manifest.json` file where I have it match a certain URL and also load up the scripts.

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["http://www.urlhere.com/videos/*"],
        "js": ["scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js", "scripts/csScript.js"]
    }
],
```

The `csScript.js` gets an attribute on the page and sends it back to the `background.js` script through a message.

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({url: getUrl()});

function getUrl() {
  url = $('meta[itemprop=contentURL]').attr('content');
  return url;
}
```

The `background.js` page gets the message with the attribute value, manipulates it, and then shows the `page_action` icon.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    url = manipulateUrl(request.url);
    chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
});

chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
console.log("url: " + url);
});
```

This all works fine and dandy on the first page load - the content script gets executed and the message is passed. However, the page has links that goes to other video...when I click on one of those, I notice that the Chrome spinner loads up a new URL in the address bar but the content script is not executed again.

When I click my `page_action` icon I get the old URL that was passed which indicates that the content script didn't go get the new one for the page.

Any ideas?

Comment: just on the offchance, but are you sure the new URL when you click a link matches that string too? Possibly it drops `http` or it becomes `https`?

Comment: Nearly positive that it's not changing. `https` never shows up for any of the video pages so I think that's not the issue. Something must be staying consistent in the DOM for the content script to not get injected again is my guess, but I'm too new to extensions development to know.  I've also tried `programmatic injection` to inject the script whenever the `page_icon` is clicked, but the same issue occurs - I get the old url data from the 'old' DOM.

Comment: Is it a fully new URL or just the hash part (window.location.hash) that changes?

Comment: Definitely a new URL. If I go back to the home page, then click on a video, it works fine. But after the video ends, I get a list of suggested videos - if I click one, the spinner spins and loads up a new URL but no content script is injected. Doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: possibly similar situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865581/chrome-extension-content-script-not-loaded-until-page-is-refreshed

Comment: Hmm, good find. That definitely helped me get closer...whenever I click on any related videos, the content script is run, but it still gives me the old URL. Possibly getting run too early and still grabbing the old video? Not sure - time for some investigation

Answer (score 2):

The URL is probably changed through history manipulation or URL fragment change, but does not actually reload the page.

If it's a URL fragment change, you can use `window.onhashchange` event.

If the URL changes completely but page does not reload, it probably is achieved with `history.pushState` or `history.replaceState` functions. Unfortunately, **they do not trigger any event**. It is, therefore, tricky to detect.

A hacky solution would be to [inject code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/934239) into the page to [replace `history.pushState` function](http://felix-kling.de/blog/2011/01/06/how-to-detect-history-pushstate/) in the page's context, so that it also does something you can detect from the content script. It can be a DOM change, a custom event, or a `window.postMessage` call.

---

Edit: from a [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865581/chrome-extension-content-script-not-loaded-until-page-is-refreshed), a better solution is to listen to `chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated` (credit to joshft91)

Comment: Is there a good way to tell if it's a fragment change? It wouldn't surprise me if it is since everything is the same except for the last fragment which is the title.  However, the Chrome spinner was spinning so I assumed it was loading a new page.

I'll take a look at your solutions and see if I can get anything work. Thanks.

Comment: See if `window.onhashchange` is triggered when it happens, e.g. set `window.onhashchange = function(e){console.dir(e);}`

Comment: judgeja linked to this possible solution (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865581/chrome-extension-content-script-not-loaded-until-page-is-refreshed) which seems to get me closer. Every time I click one of the related videos, I get an alert that the content script has run, but it still is pulling from the old, original DOM. Interesting.

Comment: It is possible that page's JavaScript updates the history state before  updating the DOM. Then you are in a race condition. Try delaying re-injection by some time.

Comment: Currently my `.onHistoryStateUpdated()` method looks like this for injecting the content script: http://jsfiddle.net/uu4tbnrw/ I'm not a Javascript developer by any means, and after some googling I'm not sure what would be the best way to delay the injection. What is the best practice for doing that?

Comment: 1) You probably don't need to reinject jQuery, 2) `setTimeout(function(){/*...*/},500)` will delay by half a second (asynchronously). This is not a "best practice" solution, only means of debugging what's going on.

Comment: Changed to: http://jsfiddle.net/uu4tbnrw/1/

The delay is definitely there but for some weird reason it's still grabbing the old URL. No idea how or why. Hmm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59593/discussion-between-joshft91-and-xan).